# I'm cooking two dishes that need to cook at different temperatures in the oven, what do I do?

Tags: oven, corn, broccoli

For dinner tonight, I am making roasted corn on the cob and some roasted broccoli as well. However, the two recipes I am using call for the corn to be cooked at 350 degrees while the broccoli is at 425. I've heard of people roasting corn at 450, but I've never tried it. Should I cook them both at 425? Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Neither broccoli nor corn is going to be all that picky regarding oven temperature, you'll be fine just splitting the difference. Since corn is the less picky of the two items, I'd go 400F. Expect the broccoli to take slightly longer than the recipe, and the corn to take less time. But don't make yourself nuts about it. Neither corn slightly more done than the recipe expects nor broccoli slightly underdone is going to ruin your meal. Don't overcook your broccoli though! BLECH!

Comment: I think everyone involved would be happier if OP just threw the broccoli out...

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Not a broccoli fan, huh? I love broccoli, *just not overcooked!*

Comment: If I don't eat broccoli regularly I begin craving it fiercely. Mmm.